# Express the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{n}{(1)(3)(5)(7)...(2n+1)}$ as a telescoping series

Tags: real-analysis

The task now is to express $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{n}{(1)(3)(5)(7)...(2n+1)}$ as a telescoping series. My attempt is to deduce a formula for simplifying $\frac{n}{(1)(3)(5)(7)...(2n+1)}$ by looking at the "shape" of the first few terms. I guess that $\frac{n}{(1)(3)(5)(7)...(2n+1)}= \frac{1}{N_n }(\frac{nC^n_0}{1}+\frac{-nC^n_1}{3}+...+\frac{(-1)^nnC^n_n}{2n+1})$, where $N_n = \frac{2^nn!}{n}$. This formula does look promising and true, though it seems difficult to prove the formula by induction and to actually use this for cancelling terms, in order to show the series is telescoping.
I think there should be(?) an even simpler way to get the formula. Any idea would be much appreciated!

Comment: the fraction is $\frac{n 2^n}{(2n)!} \; , \; $ so work out the sum of $\frac{n x^n}{(2n)!} \; , \; $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{n}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n+1)} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)} - \dfrac{1}{1\cdot 3\cdots (2n+1)}\right)$

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "hint", but +1 anyway.

Comment: Yeah this is so true! Im too stupid to learn maths. I should have come up with this easily!